# how to setup properties on Log instance

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a custom class that creates the Log instance and writes to the logs.

I call a instance of this custom class from my other objects for logging.

I notice that due to the nature of the Ninjatrader threading usage, if i set property on the log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties, the instrument property is misleading as Ninjatrader reuses the thread for multiple instruments and my logs are not accurate. so i decided to set the log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties for each event and then reset it to null.

Is there a way, i can setup a property on the Log instance of my Logger class instead of the thread?

```
public class Logger
{
    private log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }
    private string instrument;

    public Logger(string instrumentname)
    {
        Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));
        this.instrument=instrumentname;
    }

    public void Error(object msg)
    {
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["instrument"] = this.instrument;
        Log.Error(msg);
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["instrument"] = null;;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two obvious solutions suggest themselves: either simply make `instrument` part of the message, or use a sublogger per instrument, if there are not hundreds of thousands of them (`GetLogger($"Instruments.{this.instrument}")`), which has the added benefit of allowing easy customized logging per instrument. Do you have a specific requirement somewhere that `instrument` be available as a property?

Comment: I can do GetLogger($"Instruments.{this.instrument}". but how do i set a property for the sublogger? the properties seem to be for threads or global.

Comment: You don't need a property -- if the sublogger has its own distinct name, you can output that. In a pattern layout, use `%c` for the whole logger name or `%logger{2}` for the sublevel. See the [`PatternLayout` documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) for more.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that i can setup property at loggingevent and then my named logger will use it correctly.  i am using Log4net compiled in .net version 3.5. can you point to an example code where i can setup a property at a event level?

Comment: No, that is not what I'm saying. I'm saying you do not *need* properties. Properties are not required in this case. The use of properties, while obvious from an O-O perspective, is entirely unnecessary here. What you want to achieve can be done without the use of properties... am I making myself clear yet? :-) The *logger name* is the property you're looking for. It's "set" by calling `log.Error(msg)` over a logger with an appropriate name and can then be used from any layout. `LoggingEvent.LoggerName` is where it ends up, but you will never need to reference that explicitly.

Comment: To be clear: it's absolutely possible to add custom properties to each individual logging event, through the use of `LoggingEvent.Properties` and then calling `ILogger.Log`. But creating `LoggingEvent` instances explicitly makes for far more cumbersome code and should be avoided when possible, because (for starters) you can't use the convenience methods of the `ILog` interface anymore.